# Factory - take the type in the constructor consideration

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory, spring.net

Is it ok to implement factory and get the type in the constructor, so .CreateInstace() will be parameter-less or this will be antipattern and I should do my best to avoid it?

I assume that during system runtime only one predefined type should be instantiated by the factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume that during system runtime only one predefined type should be instantiated by the factory

Not necessarily as this will force you to create a factory class for each concrete type you wish to create.

Constructor injection *(i.e. providing the type via the constructor)* is usually preferred over Method injection *(i.e. providing the type via a parameter in a method call)*, but as I said what if the factory needs to create more than one type based on the parameters passed to it at run-time, then it would be more convenient to pass those parameters to the `createInstance()` method rather than creating a new factory per type.

Bottom line, I usually prefer to pass the parameters to the `createInstance()` method, and give the factory any things it need to do its job via the constructor.

Comment: so, you mean something like : public XXX CreateInstance(Type type) ?

Comment: @user1025852 It could be like that, you may pass a string, an enumeration or whatever helps the factory create the instance you want.

Answer (score 0):

For me, **No**. That is because later on your factory cannot be flexible enough or being hard during dependency injected, as such:

```
public class Factory{
    public Factory(Type t, IocContainer con){
       // param assignments
    }
    public IClass GetInstance(){
        return con.Resolve<t>();
    }
}
```

Will get you confused about what is that being injected (2 of them are unrelated each other. One is type? And other is `IocContainer`? It also makes your `Factory` has states. Moreover, how if I inject type of interface? Can your factory create a class from interface?

Rather, why don't you just accept the class itself?

```
public class Factory{
    public Factory(IClass cls){
       // param assignments
    }
    public IClass GetInstance(){
        return cls;
    }
}
```

This is more self-documented and crystal clear.

Comment: Thanks, not sure I'lm following - what do you mean by accept the class itself? I always need different instances on GetInstance()..so anyway I need this  Activator.CreateInstance etc. so what do I miss here?

Comment: Sorry looks like I missed some details here. Will the class created by the factory need to has different states (not singleton)?